# Percentile solving without full data set

Tags: percentile

Given a group of 245 students taking an exam:

- Student A scores in the 97th percentile
- Only 33.88% of students passed the exam

Find:

- Student A's rank among the 245 people

I did the math myself given my limited knowledge, and got somewhere around 238, but I wanted to check with people who actually... you know... */Math/*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second piece of information is irrelevant to the question, actually.

If he scored in the 97th percentile, it means she has scored better than 97% of scorers.

If she scored better than 237.65-240.1 people, that would mean she scored better than 237-240 people. This would put her in rank 6-9.

Rank 6 and Rank 9 can belong to 96 percentile and 98 percentile, so if you want to be more safe, say Rank 7-8.